Ordering of nested random effects in lmer
I have read in a number of different sources that specifying a nested random effect in lmer() can be done by either '(1|A) + (1|A:B)' OR '(1|A/B)', where B is nested in A. Confusingly however, when I run a model using using either syntax, the random effects are the same, but the order of the nesting changes in the output and when extracting the random effects using ranef() function. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have provided an example output below. 

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong here (the two results are equivalent), just it looks like this is somehow awkwardly implemented. What kind of help are you asking for?

Thanks for your response. I'm trying to understand why the team_name:PLID is reversed in the second output as I'm assuming this would imply something different?

I think it's a different way to write the same thing. Sure, one can criticise the software for confusing the users in this way, but as far as I see, there's otherwise nothing wrong with this.
